# Unit testing JavaScript which calls a function only if it exists, with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

For code like this:

```
export const addMediaQueryEventListener = (media, onChange) => {
  if (root.matchMedia) {
    const mediaQueryList = root.matchMedia(media);
    ...
```

How can you test both code 'branches' with Jest, i.e. when `root.matchMedia` is falsy as well as when it exists?

I can mock `matchMedia` to be a function and assert that it's called OK. But to test the other way around in order to get 100% test coverage, I'd need to mock `matchMedia` to be falsy, but also assert that it hasn't been called as a function.

Is there a way to mock the *property* `matchMedia` to be falsy whilst also spying on `matchMedia` as a function? Or would this function need to be rewritten to make it testable?

Comment: `root.matchMedia = null` or `delete root.matchMedia` to remove that key from the object.

Comment: I set `root.matchMedia` OK... but how do I then test it has not been called? (Or that no further code is executed?)

Comment: You can't test that it is not called in that case.  It doesn't exist.  Things that don't exist cannot be called. :|  You *can* test that an exception in not thrown.  If the code runs fine even with it being null/undefined, then that's a good start.

Comment: If there are side effects (or results returned) that would normally happen if it did exist, you can also test that those do not happen.

Comment: It's possible to *attempt* to call it. It would give an `is not a function` error.

Comment: Right, which you can test that an error is not thrown.

Comment: Yes that's it! I just needed to set it to e.g. null, and then call the function in my test. No additional assertions are required, because if it gave an error that it's not a function, then that would fail the test automatically. Thanks!

Comment: I confirmed that it now reports 100% test coverage

Comment: Good deal.  Glad you got that resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice from @Taplar in the comments (thanks again!) and solved it like this:

```
describe('when matchMedia is unsupported', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      root.matchMedia = undefined;
    });

    test('it does not error', () => {
      addMediaQueryEventListener(media, onChange);
    });
  });
});
```

I was getting caught up thinking what assertions to make, but simply calling the function is enough, because if it tried calling `undefined` as a function then it would error and fail the test. This brought the test coverage to 100% as desired.